# object that called for the eventListener

Tags: lua, coronasdk, addeventlistener

The situation is I need to access the object that called for the eventListener

for example: 
if i'm adding: `balls[ball]:addEventListener( "collision", removeBricks)` how can i access `balls[ball]` in removeBricks function?

```
function removeBricks(event)
    print("caller: " .. balls[ball])
    ...
end
balls[ball]:addEventListener( "collision", removeBricks)
```

what i've tried:

```
balls["ball"]:addEventListener( "collision", removeBricks(event, balls["ball"]))
```

Comment: You can give 'tag' or 'id' or 'myName' etc. to the objects and get them with those properties as: 'event.object1.myName' (in Global collisions) and as: 'self.myName' (in local collisions). Just refer the following link: http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection

Answer (score 0):

```
self -> balls[ball]
event.other -> other collided object
```

Comment: `function removeBricks(event)
  ball = event.self
  print("ball: " .. ball)
... attempt to concaten
ate upvalue 'ball' (a nil value)
stack traceback:

Comment: still `main.lua:426: attempt to concaten
ate global 'self' (a nil value)` ... code: function removeBricks(event)
   print("ball: " .. self)

Comment: Can you try to modify your code like this:
 balls["ball"]:addEventListener( "collision", removeBricks )

Comment: I mean without parameters.. I dont know if its about that, but you should try

Comment: oh I forgot most important part :D in your function decleration you should write : removeBrivks( event, self )